# Create Hive table for nested JSON data

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, hdfs

I am not able to load nested JSON data into Hive table. Below is what I have tried:

Sample Input:

```
{"DocId":"ABC","User1":{"Id":1234,"Username":"sam1234","Name":"Sam","ShippingAddress":{"Address1":"123 Main St.","Address2":null,"City":"Durham","State":"NC"},"Orders":[{"ItemId":6789,"OrderDate":"11/11/2012"},{"ItemId":4352,"OrderDate":"12/12/2012"}]}}
```

On Hive (CDH3):

```
ADD JAR /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;

CREATE TABLE json_tab(
    DocId string,
    user1 struct<Id: int, Username: string, Name:string,ShippingAddress:struct<address1:string,address2:string,city:string,state:string>,orders:array<struct<ItemId:int,orderdate:string>>>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;  

hive> select * from json_tab;
OK
NULL    null
```

I am getting `NULL`s here.

Also tried with HCatalog jar:

```
ADD JAR /home/training/Desktop/hcatalog-core-0.11.0.jar;
 
 CREATE TABLE json_tab(
    DocId string,
    user1 struct<Id: int, Username: string, Name:string,ShippingAddress:struct<address1:string,address2:string,city:string,state:string>,orders:array<struct<ItemId:int,orderdate:string>>>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe';
```

But facing below error with my `create table` statement:

> FAILED: Error in metadata: Cannot validate serde:
> org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe FAILED: Execution Error,
> return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask

What can I try to resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

you can use **org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe** class to rad the json data

you can download jar file from http://www.congiu.net/hive-json-serde/1.3.6-SNAPSHOT/cdh4/

and do following steps

```
add jar /path/to/jar/json-serde-1.3.6-jar-with-dependencies.jar;

CREATE TABLE json_tab(
    DocId string,
    user1 struct<Id: int, Username: string, Name:string,ShippingAddress:struct<address1:string,address2:string,city:string,state:string>,orders:array<struct<ItemId:int,orderdate:string>>>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe';

LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH  '/path/to/data/nested.json' INTO TABLE json_tab;

SELECT DocId, User1.Id, User1.ShippingAddress.City as city,
User1.Orders[0].ItemId as order0id,
User1.Orders[1].ItemId as order1id from json_tab;


result
ABC     1234    Durham  6789    4352
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried with the dependency jar suggested. But create table statement is throwing Error as "FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.AbstractPrimitiveJavaObjectInspector.<init>(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/objectinspector/primitive/PrimitiveObjectInspectorUtils$PrimitiveTypeEntry;)V". Can you please check and let me know what can be done? I tried on both CDH3 and CDH5.

Answer (score 0):

```
 I was getting same exception.
```

I     added following jars and it worked for me.

```
ADD JAR /home/cloudera/Data/json-serde-1.3.7.3.jar;
ADD JAR /home/cloudera/Data/hive-hcatalog-core-0.13.0.jar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using HiveQL to analyse JSON files require either `org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe` or `org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe` to work correctly.

**org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe**
This is the default [JSON SerDe from Apache](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/json-serde.html#hive-json-serde). This is commonly used to process JSON data like events. These events are represented as blocks of JSON-encoded text separated by a new line. The Hive JSON SerDe does not allow duplicate keys in map or struct key names.

**org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe**
[OpenX JSON SerDe](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde) is similar to native Apache; however, it offers multiple optional properties such as "ignore.malformed.json", "case.insensitive", and many more. In my opinion, it usually works better when dealing with nested JSON files.

See the working example below:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dbname`.`tablename` (
    `DocId` STRING,
    `User1` STRUCT<
    `Id`:INT,
`Username`:STRING,
`Name`:STRING,
`ShippingAddress`:STRUCT<
    `Address1`:STRING,
`Address2`:,
`City`:STRING,
`State`:STRING>,
`Orders`:STRUCT<
    `ItemId`:INT,
`OrderDate`:STRING>>)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
     'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION
     's3://awsexamplebucket1-logs/AWSLogs/'
```

Create table statement generated from: https://www.hivetablegenerator.com/